# Counting how many letters were repeated in the entered word

Tags: c

> Your program should read a word from the input and then sort the letters of the word alphabetically (by their ASCII codes). Next, your program should iterate through the letters of the word and compare each letter with the one following it. If these equal each other, you increase a counter by 1, making sure to then skip ahead far enough so that letters that occur more than twice are not counted again. You may assume that the word you read from the input has no more than 50 letters, and that the word is all lowercase.

I wrote a program and get these results:

- `apple` gives me 1
- `erroneousnesses` gives 5,
- but `taylor` should give me 0 however it gives 1.

How can I make `yup`, `taylor` and other words with non-repeating alphabets give me 0?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char string[51];
    int c = 0, count[26] = { 0 }, x = 0;
   
    scanf("%s", string); 
    while (string[c] != '\0') {

        if (string[c] >= 'a' && string[c] <= 'z') {
            x = string[c] - 'a';
            count[x]++;
        }

        c++;
    }

    printf("%d", count[x]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no attempt to _and then sort the letters of the word_.  Code incomplete.

Comment: Your code just prints the count for the last letter of the string (i.e. whatever x happens to be when you do the `printf()`. You're not actually checking how many letters happen more than once. But you're pretty close to success. (Assuming you're allowed to do it this way, rather than by sorting the characters.)

Comment: If your goal is simply to print the correct result then just count how many values in `count` are non-zero. But if your goal is to actually implement the specific algorithm stated in the requirement then you need to start from scratch and do what it says.

Comment: Teaching objectives are tied to the wording of an assignment. Your solution may be better (and is often worse), but there is always a reason for explicitly requiring an assignment be done a specific way. If I were your professor and had given you this assignment, it would be an absolute failure to solve it in a way you were not instructed — as you would have failed to satisfy the desired learning objective(s). Zero points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `scanf("%s", string);` may cause a buffer overflow if the input is longer than 50 bytes.
- Furthermore, you do not test the return value to check for invalid or missing input.
- counting the number of occurrences of each letter is an alternative approach to the stated problem, and OK if you are only graded based on the program output. However be aware that the program does not implement what the assignment explicitly mandates and the value you output is incorrect anyway.
- the output value should be the number of counts that are `>= 2`. Printing the value of `count[x]` is meaningless.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char str[51];
    int dup = 0;
    int count['z' - 'a' + 1] = { 0 };
   
    if (scanf(" %50[a-z]", str) == 1) {
        for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
            if (++count[str[i] - 'a'] == 2)
                dup++;
        }
        printf("%d\n", dup);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the assignment did say sort. I know that its not needed but it is an explicit requirement

Comment: @pm100: I agree and modified the answer to this regard.

Comment: Thanks a lot this has helped me a lot the programme was neat and simple for beginners like me. Really appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

to answer your specifc question

```
printf("%d", count[x]);
```

prints the count of number of appearances of the last letter.

```
taylor => 1 (r occurs 1 time)
apple => 1 (e once)
erroneousnesses => 5 (s count)
```

you need to loop over count array adding all counts > 1